# Matlab: Passing varargin into a sub-sub-function

Tags: matlab

So the fairly common solution to passing variable list of arguments into a subfunction is to pass in:

```
function out = foo(arg1, arg2, varargin)
   % do something
   out = foo2(arg1+arg2, varargin{:});
end
```

where varargin{:} is the comma-seperated unpacking of a cell-array.

But I run into the issue when I want to pass the variable list of arguments into a **SUB-subfunction**, for example

```
function out = foo2(arg1, varargin)
    tempOut = foo3(varargin{:});
    out = arg1 + tempOut; % Assuming I guarantee nargin >= 2
end
```

### The problem that I run into is:

varargin passed into foo2: 1 x nargin cell

varargin passed into foo3: 1 x 1 cell, content: 1 x nargin cell

How do I unpack correctly so that I can pass into foo3 properly?
Thanks!

Comment: oops, sorry that was a typo, i do call it with the braces in my code

Comment: What is the problem with `foo3`? Can you give a reproducible example?

Comment: If you're calling `foo3(varargin{:});` rather than `foo3(varargin);`, I don't see how `varargin` would be a "1 x 1 cell, content: 1 x nargin cell" inside `foo3`. Does your actual code do other things?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to change the format of `foo2` and `foo3`.

If `foo2` is:

```
function out = foo2(arg1, myvarargin)
    %// Now myvarargin is a cell array.
    tempOut = foo3(myvarargin);
    out = arg1 + tempOut; % Assuming I guarantee nargin >= 2
end
```

and its called as

```
out = foo2(arg1+arg2, varargin);
```

It will work (dependent on the declaration of `foo3`).
This is because you don't use "variable arguments" in `foo2` but you have an input that is a cell array, that can vary of size. But it will always be a single intput.